# Error: "Assigning result of a function call where the function has no return" for a simple login GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm trying to make a simple login GUI which will have "two-factor authentication". I'm having a problem with line 24 where I get the error "Assigning result of a function call, where the function has no return"

Here is the code:

import tkinter as tk

```
def test_my_button():
    frame_auth.tkraise()

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_geometry("200x200")

frame_login = tk.Frame(root)
frame_login.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

lbl_username = tk.Label(frame_login, text='Username:')
lbl_username.pack()

ent_username = tk.Entry(frame_login, bd=3)
ent_username.pack(pady=5)

lbl_password = tk.Label(frame_login, text="Password:")
lbl_password.pack()

ent_password = tk.Entry(frame_login, bd=3, show = "*")
ent_password.pack(pady=5)

###ERROR HERE###
btn_login = tk.Button(frame_login, text = "Login", command = test_my_button).pack()

frame_auth = tk.Frame(root)
frame_auth.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

frame_login.tkraise()

root.mainloop()
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

That's a linter warning, not an error. It's telling you that `pack` doesn't return anything, so it doesn't make sense to assign it to a variable.

You want the call to `pack` on its own line after assigning `btn_login`:

```
btn_login = tk.Button(frame_login, text = "Login", command = test_my_button)
btn_login.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me with a similar problem!